# How to shuffle two strings to a set of string in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

How can I shuffle two strings s||t (shuffle(s, t)) with the given requirement that the first char always stands in front of the second one in s and t as well no matter we shuffle. The result returns as a set of strings without duplicates.

I have the following test:

```
print(shuffle('ab', 'cd'))
```

Result:

```
['abcd', 'acbd', 'acdb', 'cabd', 'cadb', 'cdab']
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This method will shuffle two strings and return a list of shuffles between them where the order of the characters is the same as in the original strings. If there are duplicate characters there will be duplicate results as well.

```
def shuffle(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) == 1:
        return [s2[:i] + s1 + s2[i:] for i in range(len(s2) + 1)]
    if len(s2) == 1:
        return [s1[:i] + s2 + s1[i:] for i in range(len(s1) + 1)]
    return [s1[0]+ s for s in shuffle(s1[1:], s2)] + [s2[0] + s for s in shuffle(s1, s2[1:])]

print shuffle("ab", "cd")
```

It works by getting the first character of each string and recursively shuffling the rest and adding this character to each element in the list. When there is one character remaining on each of the strings it returns a list where the character is added in each position of the other string. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So you can apply a condition on final shuffled list to generate a new list from the shuffled one:

```
S=shuffle('ab','cd')
nl=[]
for w in S:
    if(w.index('a')<w.index('b') and  w.index('c')<w.index('d')):
    nl.append(w)
```

So nl is your new list as per your requirement:)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, this should work. Note, as you add letters to this, it becomes a long running problem. 4 letters have 6 possible combination for each entry in the list. 8 letters have 5,040 possible combinations for each entry in the list.

```
import random
import math

InputList = ['ab','cd']
PossibleUniqueCombinations = math.factorial(len("".join(InputList))-1)
print (PossibleUniqueCombinations)

TargetList = []
UniqueCombinationList = []
for lst in InputList:
    UniqueCnt = 0
    FirstChar = lst[0]
    TheRest = list(lst[1:])
    while UniqueCnt < PossibleUniqueCombinations:
        if InputList.index(lst) == 0:
            LeftList = []
        else:
            LeftList = InputList[0:InputList.index(lst)]
        RightList = list(InputList[InputList.index(lst)+1:])
        TargetList = LeftList + TheRest + RightList
        TargetStr = ''.join(TargetList)
        TargetStr = ''.join(random.sample(TargetStr, len(TargetStr)))
        ShuffledStr = FirstChar + ''.join(TargetStr)
        try:
            FndIdx = UniqueCombinationList.index(ShuffledStr)
        except ValueError:
            UniqueCombinationList.append(ShuffledStr)
            UniqueCnt += 1

for combo in UniqueCombinationList:
    print(combo)
```